# Why @Async Annotation Clauses AopInvocationException?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-async, spring-aspects

Here is a code snippet:

```
@GetMapping("/account")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public UserDTO getAccount(Principal principal) {
    ...
    janitorService.cleanUp((AbstractAuthenticationToken) principal);
    ...
}

@Component
public class JanitorService {
  ...
  @Async
  public boolean cleanUp(AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken){
    ...
    return true;
  }
```

}

and there is an async configuration class.

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public boolean com.mycompany.myteam.JanitorService.cleanUp(org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken)
```

The exception won't be thrown after @Async is removed. The reason I use @Async is to kick off a thread. Why does it cause the exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will an aspect be executed asynchronously if I put @Async method on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275121/will-an-aspect-be-executed-asynchronously-if-i-put-async-method-on-it)

Comment: Not on the same topic, but it is nice to learn some related knowledge.

Comment: It is the same topic, I am explaining exactly why your exception occurs.

Comment: I have another look and see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `@Async` methods with return, the return should be a `Future<T>` not a `T`.
Try returning `Future<Boolean>`
Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: Thanks for the info. I only read a sample code with the void return type.