# Spring AOP @Afterreturning aspect blocks api call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have an @Afterreturning aspect.

```
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(****)",returning = "returnValue")
    public void auditableUponReturn(final JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) {
       //takes 500 ms
      }
```

I have an endpoint which invokes this aspect

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    @AspectInvoker
    public Name getName(){
       //takes 100 ms
    }
```

when I call this endpoint I am expecting this endpoint to take 100 ms and return back instantly while my aspect related code is in process. But the endpoint doesnot return until aspect related code is complete.

Is this expected? Any way to get around this so that performance of apis is not impacted by aspect related code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behavior you are experiencing is expected. The reason for this is that your registered Aspect operates in the same thread as your endpoint.

You can utilize `@Async` (along with `@EnableAsync`) to execute the Aspect logic in a separate thread. **But this approach creates a new thread each time your method is called.** It is questionable whether this gives you a significant performance advantage over synchronous execution of the aspect.

You might find this thread helpful for a more comprehensive understanding: [Will an aspect be executed asynchronously if I put @Async method on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275121/will-an-aspect-be-executed-asynchronously-if-i-put-async-method-on-it)

Comment: Thanks for linking to my answer. This works, assuming the OP **(a)** works with Spring AOP, not with native AspectJ, **(b)** is OK with auditing being done asynchronously, while his application continues working. If auditing ought to be able to block further execution based on some condition, `@Async` is not an option. In that case, the OP should ask himself why his auditing aspect is so slow and how to make it faster.

Comment: Thank you for the additional input! I completely agree with your points of view. I hope it was okay to directly link to your answer. As a newcomer on the platform, I was unable to add a comment or select any kind of indication for a potential duplicate, so I took the liberty of writing it directly as an answer with a note. :)

Comment: By all means, thanks for joining SO and contributing. It is encouraging to see a "newbie" - I know you joined the platform 8 years ago -  trying to support other community members before even asking his/her own first question. SO is successful because of its community, which makes it more than the sum of its constituent parts. SO is more than just cheap input for ChatGPT.